# how to add a texture image for my whole shapes in three.js

Tags: 3d, three.js, textures, texture-mapping, geo

I create a 3d map with "three.js" with geo json information but I want to add a texture image for my whole map not for part by part one image for whole shapes.
I have something like this: http://omidgharib.ir/Map3D

and i want to render it like this: http://omidgharib.ir/Map3D/images/map.jpg

how can i do this?

Comment: This issue has come up before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bthree.js%5D+extrude+shape+texture. Fortunately you have UVs, they just need to be rescaled. Experiment with a simple shape -- like a triangle -- so you understand what is happening.

Comment: @WestLangley I got confused about this I don't know how to do this task can you help me more?